# how to use MAX function in case statement under sum expression in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  SELECT A.institution,
         A.acad_career,
         A.emplid,
         a.strm,
         NVL(
             SUM(
                 CASE
                     WHEN     A.repeat_candidate IN ('N', 'Y')
                          AND A.CRSE_GRADE_OFF != 'F' THEN
                         MAX(grade_points)
                     ELSE
                         (grade_points)
                 END
                ),
             0
            )
             AS GPA,
         NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.repeat_candidate = 'N' THEN A.UNT_TAKEN END), 0) AS TAKEN,
         a.acad_prog
    FROM ps_stdnt_enrl A, ps_STDNT_CLAS_D_VW B
   WHERE     A.emplid = B.emplid
         AND A.class_nbr = B.class_nbr
         AND A.strm = B.strm
         AND A.acad_career = B.acad_career
         AND a.STDNT_ENRL_STATUS = 'E'
         AND a.emplid LIKE '06381313011%'
GROUP BY a.emplid,
         a.acad_career,
         a.institution,
         a.acad_prog,
         A.strm
```

This query work fine without max function bt here problems is that student can repeat passed course so at this condition max value is required but its return error not a single group function.

Comment: What is the question? Is this giving an error? If so, what error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest aggregation functions.
Try this trick with nested queries:

```
select 
 data.institution
,data.acad_career
,data.emplid
,data.strm
,NVL(SUM(data.GPA), 0) as GPA
,data.TAKEN
,data.acad_prog
from   
(SELECT A.institution,
         A.acad_career,
         A.emplid,
         a.strm,
        MAX(grade_points) AS GPA,
         NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN a.repeat_candidate = 'N' THEN A.UNT_TAKEN END), 0) AS TAKEN,
         a.acad_prog
    FROM ps_stdnt_enrl A, ps_STDNT_CLAS_D_VW B
   WHERE     A.emplid = B.emplid
         AND A.class_nbr = B.class_nbr
         AND A.strm = B.strm
         AND A.acad_career = B.acad_career
         AND a.STDNT_ENRL_STATUS = 'E'
         AND a.emplid LIKE '06381313011%'
GROUP BY a.emplid,
         a.acad_career,
         a.institution,
         a.acad_prog,
         A.strm
) data
group by  
 data.institution
,data.acad_career
,data.emplid
,data.strm
,data.TAKEN
,data.acad_prog
```

Comment: thanks miyazawa ...its not work according to my requirement, i required max grade of those students who repeats their passed course .e.g A student take course 1 and 2nd semester and got grade c+ and take this course again in 3rd semester and take grade B+ then query should pic best grade when we open the report for 3rd semester but when we open report for 2nd semester its  should return c+ grade ..